# XPath discriminative text extraction

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Let's assume I have an XPath selector pointing to the following piece of HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello <a href="foo">fantastic</a> world</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>first</td>
            <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>second</td>
            <td>row</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I would like to extract the text from it in a way that ignores `<a>` tags only so I would get:

```
['Hello fantastic world', 'first', 'row', 'second', 'row'].
```

Notice that `fantastic` was treated like it belonged to the `<p>` tag.

The problem is that:

- with `selector.xpath('.//text()').extract()`, I get

  `['Hello', 'fantastic', 'world', 'first', 'row', 'second', 'row']`
- with `'selector.xpath(string(./)).extract()'`, I get

  `['Hello fantastic world first row second row']`

If anyone knows how to crack this it will be deeply appreciated !

Comment: Thanks for the edits kjhughes. @whoever downvoted, can you please elaborate as to why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//*[not(self::a)][not(*) or a]
```

will select all elements other than `a` elements that have no children or only `a` children:

```
<p>Hello <a href="foo">fantastic</a> world</p>
<td>first</td>
<td>row</td>
<td>second</td>
<td>row</td>
```

In **XPath 2.0**, take the string values of those elements directly in XPath:

```
//*[not(self::a)][not(*) or a]/string()
```

Result, as requested:

```
Hello fantastic world
first
row
second
row
```

In **XPath 1.0**, iterate over the results and extract the string values in the hosting language.

Answer (score 1):

And another xpath 2.0 alternative:

```
//(p,//td)/string()
```

Same output.